# Configure Office 2013 add-in according to user specific settings

Tags: office-addins, office365-apps, office-js

We try to make our Office 2013/16 html/javascript taskpane add-in to work against our customers own servers, running our software, to display their pictures, and add them to Word/PowerPoint. Our customers have one or more domains they would want to configure so the add-in connects to one of them. If we ship this add-in on Office Store, we don't know all the domains our customers might want to configure, so the App domain list would be empty.

1. Is it somehow possible to add a App Domain to the manifest during runtime based on user input?
2. Is it possible to put a manifest file on a CDN that we can update when we want? This is btw not the solution we want as this requires internet access, and not all of our customers have that. But I'm still curious about the answer to this one.
3. Any other solutions to this problem?

Edit: 
Our product is a web based product. We have a html widget inside our product which can be used in for instance a CMS, or as we try to do now, add it to the taskpane add-in for word and Powerpoint. The widget can be located on a specific url, on a given domain. Since the widget is part of our product, and our customers are choosing which domain they run our server product on, we can't preconfigure this in the add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 1.Is it somehow possible to add a App Domain to the manifest during runtime based on user input?

No. There is no way we can config the manifest at the runtime.

> > Is it possible to put a manifest file on a CDN that we can update when we want? This is btw not the solution we want as this requires internet access, and not all of our customers have that. But I'm still curious about the answer to this one.

No. In this scenario, we need to publish the manifest to the Office store.

Based on my understanding, the domains specify in the Office add-in only enable users navigate the HTML page in the task pane.

> work against our customers own servers, running our own software, to display their pictures

Usually, this does not require the app domain configuration. Would you mind share more detail how the users connect their service?

Comment: Thanks for your post. Domains that are not listed in the AppDomain section of the manifest will open in a browser window outside the taskpane if navigated to. So if the user enters their hostname for our server product, we can't navigate to that domain and still remain in the taskpane. I edited my initial post with more details.

Comment: At present, the apps for Office doesn’t support configure the trusted domains at runtime. You can submit the feedback from link below if you want apps for Office to support this feature.
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/